# @SpringBootTest not working (execution throwing NullPointerException)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, integration-testing

My Spring Boot application not loading Spring context when I use the `@SpringBootTest` annotation to create an integration test class.

How to solve this problem?

My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.7.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <groupId>br.com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>authorization-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>authorization-server</name>
    <description>Authorization Server OAuth2</description>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <docker.repository>docker-repo.example.com.br</docker.repository>
        <docker.buildArg.appId>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</docker.buildArg.appId>
        <spring-jdbc.version>5.2.16.RELEASE</spring-jdbc.version>
        <oauth.version>2.3.7.RELEASE</oauth.version>
        <jwt.version>1.0.11.RELEASE</jwt.version>
        <opentracing-spring-jaeger>3.3.1</opentracing-spring-jaeger>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-undertow</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-jdbc.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
            <version>${oauth.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>${jwt.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.opentracing.contrib</groupId>
            <artifactId>opentracing-spring-jaeger-web-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${opentracing-spring-jaeger}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>application.properties</include>
                </includes>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT*.java</include>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/resources</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Version>${project.version}</Version>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.15.16</version>
                <configuration>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.repository}/${project.artifactId}:${project.version}</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>${docker.repository}/my-image:0.0.1</from>
                                <maintainer>app@example.com.br</maintainer>
                                <env>
                                    <APP_NAME>${project.build.finalName}.jar</APP_NAME>
                                </env>
                                <tags>
                                    <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                                </tags>
                                <ports>
                                    <port>8080</port>
                                </ports>
                                <assembly>
                                    <user>app:app:root</user>
                                    <mode>dir</mode>
                                    <basedir>/</basedir>
                                    <inline>
                                        <fileSets>
                                            <fileSet>
                                                <directory>${project.basedir}/target</directory>
                                                <outputDirectory>/home/app</outputDirectory>
                                                <includes>
                                                    <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                                                </includes>
                                            </fileSet>
                                        </fileSets>
                                    </inline>
                                </assembly>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>

</project>
```

My `application-test.properties`:

```
# DATABASE CONFIGURATION
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=sa

# POOL CONNECTIONS DATABASE
spring.datasource.hikari.minimum-idle=5
spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10
spring.datasource.hikari.idle-timeout=10000

# JPA CONFIGURATION
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

My repository class:

```
@Repository
public class UserJdbcRepository {

    private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public UserJdbcRepository(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    public Optional<User> findByDocument(String document) {
        // implementation
    }

}
```

My test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
public class UserJdbcRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private UserJdbcRepository subject;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        subject.findByDocument("000.000.001-91"); // subject throwing NullPointerException
    }

}
```

Comment: Are there any debug logs of this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe repositories are not getting auto wired properly.

if you are using JUnit 4

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class) 
public class UserJdbcRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private UserJdbcRepository subject;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        subject.findByDocument("000.000.001-91"); 
    }

}
```

if you are using JUnit 5

`@ActiveProfiles("test")
@SpringBootTest
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
public class UserJdbcRepositoryIT {

    @Autowired
    private UserJdbcRepository subject;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        subject.findByDocument("000.000.001-91"); 
    }
}`

Comment: Thank you for your help, the `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` annotation solved my problem!
I believe in this Spring version this annotation is required to run the test, but in higher versions for example 2.5.x the `@SprintBootTest` annotation is enough.